# How to initial correctly between two class

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I want to make sure that in class Home could invoke class HUD, and these two part code could be test Okay but when I run in Xcode, it crash and show up a issue:

**"Fatal error: use of unimplemented initializer 'init(size:)' for class 'LeftBehind.HUD'"**

I hope anyone could told me how to fixed it, thanks.

```
    import UIKit
    import SpriteKit

    class HUD: SKScene {

        let positionX:CGFloat
        let positionY:CGFloat
        let sceneSelf: SKScene

        let year = SKLabelNode()
        let month = SKLabelNode()
        let day = SKLabelNode()
        let hour = SKLabelNode()
        let minute = SKLabelNode()

        init(positionX:CGFloat,positionY:CGFloat,scene:SKScene) {
            self.positionX = positionX
            self.positionY = positionY
            self.sceneSelf = scene
            super.init()
        }

        required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
        }

        func hudShow() {
            year.fontName = "Arial"
            year.fontSize = 70
            year.text = "This is a year"
            year.fontColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            year.position = CGPoint(x: positionX , y: positionY)
            sceneSelf.addChild(year)
        }
    }
```

Below class invoke above class

```
import SpriteKit
class Home: SKScene {
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        let hud = HUD(positionX: frame.midX, positionY: frame.midY, scene: self)
        hud.hudShow()
    }
}
```

Edit: Upload another way which could work but not perfect way which I want to implement with initial rather than function refer.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you attempting to present two scenes in the view? An `SKView` can present only one `SKScene` at a time.

Comment: i think hes trying to keep a reference between his menu scene and his game scene or something

Comment: @0x141E No, I want to make a class, which could be used as a general UI group(called "HUD") and it will show up in many other scene, and I also don't want to setting this function each time, so I need a initial.

Comment: @hamobi Hey buddy, let't me show your another example

Answer (score 0):

instead of calling `super.init()` call `super.init(size size: CGSize)`

you can use your SKView's `bounds.size` property to pass into that initializer.